# Need help copying files to all directories recursively

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line, terminal

I have a bunch of folders with different names on which I am trying to copy one file to . I am not sure on how to do that with a wildcard charachter. Can anyone please help me out on this? So far I am stuck with this command

```
cp -R custom.css
```

As you can see I am trying to copy custom.css to all directories. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

A simple for loop:

```
for d in path/to/dir1/ path/to/dir2/ path/to/dir3/; do
   cp custom.css "$d"
done
```

---

**EDIT::** Run this from parent directory to copy a file to all the subdirectories:

```
for d in */; do
   cp custom.css "$d"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. As I mentioned before I don't have the names to the directories I can't specify any path names. How can I copy the files to all the sub directories once I am in the parent directory?? This is what i have

`menus > for d in . ; do cp custom.css "$d" done`

Its not working

Answer (score 0):

First, get used to loops in (let's assume you are using) bash. Try creating 3 **test** directories, say d1, d2, and d3.

Try:

```
for d in d1 d2 d3; do echo $d; done
```

to make sure you have the list correct, then do:

```
for d in d1 d2 d3; do cp custom.css $d/; done
```

to copy your file.

Now check to make sure the file was copied.

O.k., now that it works, copy the file to your **actual** directories.

Comment: I  understand that and it worked. But I don't know the name of of all the directories. They will all be wildcard directories

Comment: I can only comment on my own answers so far. Just 2 things ... first glad you got it, and second, I "forward-agree" with gniourf_gniourf, quote the $d. Maybe brace it as well.

Answer (score 0):

for **all** subdirectories recursively:

```
find . -type d -execdir cp /full/path/to/custom.cs . \;
```

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind I got it. This is what I did

```
for d in ~/Desktop/menus/*/ ; do cp custom.css $d; done
```

Comment: You need to quote `$d`. Now what does your answer add to anubhava's answer (that you should upvote and accept)?